# How to replace hyperlink inside <span?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a span inside div and I want to replace the hyperlink inside it each time I call load function. Currently, my code keeps appending hyper links. Is there a way to replace a hyperlink with a new one each time I call the function? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** I don't want to empty div. I only want to clear the span and insert a new hyperlink

```
function load(Url,myImage) {    
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.textContent = 'Link';
  link.href = Url;
  document.getElementById('where_to_insert').appendChild(link);
}
```

and div that holds the span:

```
<div class="top">
  ....
  ....
  <span id="where_to_insert"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: [`replaceChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild)?

Comment: Thanks for reply. At start span is empty so i tried you code now it even doesn't create the hyperlink inside span!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w3p8wfgy/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var link = '<a href="' + Url + '">Link</a>';
document.getElementById('where_to_insert').innerHTML = link;
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Is it possible to create 3 different hyperlinks using this method and replace all the three hyperlinks each time i call the function ?

Comment: Yep. Just build all three as a single HTML string, then set innerHTML to that string.

Comment: What if `Url` comes from an untrusted source? In that case, setting `innerHTML` is not a good choice right?

Answer (score 0):

Top method is right, but it willn't work in IE. If you need that, you must create `<a>` element separately.

So, most crossbrowser code will like that :)

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = Url;
link.innerHtml = '
document.getElementById('where_to_insert').innerHTML = link;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to create the anchor tag every time you call `load`

if not then you can use the following

HTML

```
<div class="top">
<span id="where_to_insert">
Anchor here
<a href="" id='somAnc'></a>
</span>
</div>
```

JS

```
function load(Url,myImage) {    
  document.getElementById('somAnc').href=Url;
}
load('google.com');
setTimeout(function(){   // Just for testing href will be update after 5sec
load('mozilla.com')
},5000)
```

[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/o1bt6pfk/5/)